# Sharepoint lookup to populate form value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I'm working on leave request SharePoint form. I have two lists :

- a first list (list1) will record the request of form submission and calculate the remaining leave
- then update the second list (list2) with the column emp_name,manager,balance leave.

I want to do is :

For example if an employee has a leave balance of 6 in list2 then when i open a new form and pick up the employee_name then the  leave balance of 6 for that employee should show under "balance leave" . Is it possible to achieve it?

Field Type of remaining balance 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example below for your reference, when use enter the value in emp_name field and blur, the value will auto fill in the balance leave field.

Add the code below into script editor web part in new form page in list2.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var listname = "list2";
    $("input[title='emp_name']").blur(function(){
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$filter=emp_name eq '"+$(this).val()+"'";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.results.length>0){
                    var item = data.d.results[0];
                    $("input[title='balance leave']").val(item.balance_x0020_leave);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

If the emp_name field is a lookup field, we need use the code below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var listname = "list2";
    $("select[title='emp_name']").change(function(){
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$filter=emp_name eq '"+$(this).val()+"'";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.results.length>0){
                    var item = data.d.results[0];
                    $("input[title='balance leave']").val(item.balance_x0020_leave);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer brother, i very new to share point , may i know where i can enter the script you have mentioned?

Comment: LZ_MSFT Could you please show me with screenshots on where i need to add the script please?

Comment: Add code into script editor web part in newform.aspx page.

Comment: i know im doing it wrong. but i couldnt make it work. I have entered the script then selected the emp_name on list1 form but it doesnt picks up the remaining balance

Comment: Check the updated code. If still not works, I suggest you provide the screenshots about your form and fields type.

Comment: i'm going to try this now and let you know..Thank you

Comment: here is the field type for remaining leave i have added the screenshot. Still not able to get it work :(

Comment: I suggest you provide all the field types and field names in list2.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach that througt REST API.
Try to get the Balance leave depending in the employee control with a rest api query. then store the result in a variable and play with it with rules.

Comment: @ahemed Bauchaala , not sure whats that. its my second week working on share point. Can you give me an example on how i  can achieve with REST API please?

Comment: Here an exemple http://johnliu.net/blog/2012/4/26/infopath-2010-query-using-the-rest-interface.html

Comment: You are welcome, give a vote if you found that it was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace following line in LZ_MSFt code

```
$("input[title='balance leave']").val(item.balance_x0020_leave);
```

replace with:

```
$("input[title='balance leave']").val(item.Remaining_x0020_balance);
```